# Postgres - sum/count by month

Tags: postgresql

My logic watches multiple entities called `nodes` and collects data about them daily. Data looks like this:

```
table node_snapshots:

id.         node_id.         mined.         mined_amount.           created_at
373.        2.               0.             0.                      2021-06-23 00:00:02
372.        4.               1.             1109851671.             2021-06-23 00:00:02
371.        3.               0.             0.                      2021-06-23 00:00:02
370.        2.               0.             0.                      2021-06-22 00:00:02
369.        4.               0.             0.                      2021-06-22 00:00:02
368.        3.               1.             1109851671.             2021-06-22 00:00:02
368.        2.               0.             0.                      2021-06-21 00:00:02
367.        4.               0.             0.                      2021-06-21 00:00:02
366.        3.               0.             0.                      2021-06-21 00:00:02
365.        2.               1.             1109851671.             2021-06-20 00:00:02
364.        4.               0.             0.                      2021-06-20 00:00:02
363.        3.               0.             0.                      2021-06-20 00:00:02
...
```

Now I want to get the following information:

- What is the sum of all mined/mined_amount of a subset of nodes (f.e. (1,2,3)) per day/week/month?

Something like this:

```
date.                      sum_mined.       sum_mined_amount.
2021-06-30 00:00:02        5.               5549258355.             
2021-05-30 00:00:02        2.               2219703342.
2021-04-30 00:00:02        3.               3329555013.                    
...
```

I tried smth like

```
SELECT  
   date_trunc('month', s.created_at) as date, 
   sum(CAST (s.mined AS DOUBLE PRECISION)) sum_mined, 
   sum(CAST (s.mined_amount AS DOUBLE PRECISION)) sum_mined_amount 
FROM node_snapshots s 
INNER JOIN ( 
   SELECT 
      node_id, 
      max(created_at) maxdate 
   FROM node_snapshots 
   WHERE node_id in (1,2,3,4) 
   GROUP by node_id, date_trunc('month', created_at) 
) g ON 
   g.node_id = s.node_id AND g.maxdate = s.created_at 
GROUP BY date 
ORDER BY date desc 
LIMIT 72;
```

But that only works for the hourly timeframe.

Comment: It is unclear what your query wants to achieve.

Comment: I thought I lay that out pretty clear. I described WHAT information I want to have and how the result should be structured. If there is any more information I can provide I would be happy doing that.